# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'secret'

Tags: django

I am working on a [django tenants](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) app. I want to store stripe api keys to db. Here is my code

```
class ExternalKeys(models.Model):
    public = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    webhook_secret = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
```

The model has been migrated and I have added a single set of data to db. But when I print out to terminal from view it shows empty and if I print out and instance it throws the above error.

```
api_key = ExternalKeys.objects.order_by('pk').first().secret
print(api_key)
```

I can see the data in django admin
[image]

Comment: ExternalKeys.objects.all().order_by('pk').first().secret ?

Comment: api_key = ExternalKeys.objects.all(). gives an empty queryset, so same error if I print it.

Comment: I believe that your code and your admin panel dont connect the same DB. Can you try to create a record from code and see if it's appear in admin ?